# Split JSON in N strings

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am trying to separate a json into several pieces
n times depending on the size of the json and the limit of characters within a field, for example, if the json occupies 16000 characters I divide it by 4000 (which is the limit per field) and thus divide it into 4 pieces type string[0], string[1],string[2],string[3] and then print them to the screen.

I have this code but it always gives me the following error:

Error: Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length

```
var splitA= [];
  
function separatedFields(nCharacter, valueDeInfo){
  
  var limit = 4000;
  var split= [];
  var nfield= Math.ceil((nCharacter)/limit);
  var begin= 0;
  var end= 4000;
   
  for( i=0; i < nfield; i++ ){
    if( i == nfield-1){
    split[i] = valueDeInfo.slice(begin,end);  
    begin= end;
    end= nCharacter;
   }else{
    split[i] = valueDeInfo.slice(begin,end);  
    begin= end;
    end= end+ 4000;
   }
  }
    return split;
}
 
  
   splitA = separatedFields(nCharacter, valueDeInfo);
   Write("ARRAY FIRST 4000: "+ splitA[0]);
```

I tried create a data extension field with no character limit, but it doesnt' work for me, because it is not able to put the entire json in the field, that's what i'm triying to slipt the json an then put on differents fields and concatenate it after that

Comment: Please, as explained in the comments to your similar question: don't split it. Rather create a data extension field with no character limit. You will need to clear the number for character count in field definition (which can only be done in Email Studio). This way, you will be able to store your complete JSON in a single DE field.

Comment: Hi! I tried those trick But it doesn’t work for me.. in this moment i Need to print out the values. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I am confused what trick did not work and why do you need to split it to print out the values... in general it is terrible practice to break up a JSON into multiple pieces because that is just ripe with risk of corruption or misalignment so I would recommend searching for another way

Comment: Marking as duplicate as it's same question asked before. If you can show how it's a different question or adjust it to focus on why that solution does not work for you. then we can look to reopen...